# Using CSS and Bootstrap, how can you set a background image that is 1/3 of the screen size?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am doing the following using inline CSS with Bootstrap. However, it is not working.

```
<div class="container" class="img-responsive" class="img-fluid" style="background-image: url('img/projects_cover.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center center; width: 100%; height: 100%">
```

Comment: What do you mean, you want it 1/3 of the screen size? Please post an image of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your `background-size: cover` means "cover all div by this image 100%"

Change it to `background-size: 33% 100%;`

[DEMO LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/qjvrodgx/)

```html
<div class="container" class="img-responsive" class="img-fluid" style="background-color: red; background-image: url('https://gyazo.com/79d8af055c1ff36c01c01fb530d896de.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 33% 100%; background-position: center center; width: 100%; height: 200px; border: 1px solid red;">
```

P.s. you can write `class="container img-responsive img-fluid"`
Instead of `class="container" class="img-responsive" class="img-fluid"`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this...

```css
.container {
  /* here Background color is optional*/
  background: #000 url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535702181453-dae70f42a117?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=504cb79cca4c38e00b57228e48441e81&dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb");
  background-size: 33%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  /* optional*/
  
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">The Image is in the backround</div>
```